# contact form sends email without data

Tags: php, contact-form

Hello I'm hoping someone can take a peek at my code and give me a clue as to what might be causing this, as It has me stumped.  When I test the send button, everything happens as promised and I get the sent msg and the redirect, but email shows all the fields without any answers that I enter.  Here is the form:

```
<form action="contactformprocess.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="form1" id="form1">
            <p>
              <label><span class="GoldText">What is your movie about?</span> What are you trying to tell us?<span id="What">
              <textarea name="what" id="what" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
              <span id="countWhat">&nbsp;</span><span class="textareaRequiredMsg">Please Fill.</span><span class="textareaMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Why is this Project Important to you?  <span class="GoldText">What is it's purpose?</span><span id="why">
              <textarea name="why" cols="45" rows="5" id="why"></textarea>
              <span id="countwhy">&nbsp;</span><span class="textareaRequiredMsg">Please Fill.</span><span class="textareaMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>What will people gain from watching it?<br />
              <span class="GoldText">What sentiments are we left with?</span><span id="Contribution">
              <textarea name="contribution" cols="45" rows="5" id="contribution"></textarea>
              <span id="countContribution">&nbsp;</span><span class="textareaMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></label>
            </p>
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Where and when is it shot? (For dated events)</legend>
              <p>
                <label>Location:
                  <input type="text" name="location" id="location" />
                </label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label>Date(s): <span id="EventDateStart">
                <input name="eventdatestart" type="text" id="eventdatestart" />
                <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></label>
              to<span id="EventDateEnd">
              <label>
                <input name="eventdateend" type="text" id="eventdateend" />
              </label>
<span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>              </p>
              <p>
                <label>Time: <span id="EventTimeStart">
                <input name="eventtimestart" type="text" id="eventtimestart" />
</span></label>
              </p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Please tell us who you are.</legend>
              <p>
                <label>Name                </label>
                <span id="ClientName">
                <label>
                  <input type="text" name="clientname" id="clientname" />
                </label>
              <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Please Fill.</span></span></p>
              <p>
                <label>Phone
                  <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" value="optional" />
                </label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label>Email                <span id="OnlineContact">
                <input type="text" name="onlinecontact" id="onlinecontact" />
                <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Please Fill.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label>What other details help clarify your vision?<span id="FinalThoughts">
                  <textarea name="finalthoughts" cols="45" rows="5" id="finalthoughts"></textarea>
                <span id="countFinalThoughts">&nbsp;</span><span class="textareaMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <label>Send
                  <input name="button" type="submit" id="button" onclick="MM_validateForm('clientname','','R','phone','','NisNum','onlinecontact','','RisEmail','what','','R','why','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Send" />
                </label>
              </p>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
```

This is the php:

```
/* Email Variables */
$emailSubject = 'contactformprocess'; /*Make sure this matches the name of your file*/
$webMaster = 'wavelengthfredy@gmail.com';

/*design by Mark Leroy @ http://www.helpvid.net*/

/* Data Variables */
$what = $_REQUEST['what'];
$why = $_REQUEST['why'];
$contribution = $_REQUEST['contribution'];
$location = $_REQUEST['location'];
$eventdatestart = $_REQUEST['eventdatestart'];
$eventdateend = $_REQUEST['eventdateend'];
$eventtimestart = $_REQUEST['eventtimestart'];
$clientname = $_REQUEST['clientname'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$onlinecontact = $_REQUEST['onlinecontact'];
$finalthoughts = $_REQUEST['finalthoughts'];



$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
What: $what <br>
Why: $why <br>
Contribution: $contribution <br>
Location: $location <br>
EventDateStart: $eventdatestart <br>
EventDateEnd: $eventdateend <br>
EventTimeStart: $eventtimestart <br>
ClientName: $clientname <br>
Phone: $phone <br>
OnlineContact: $onlinecontact <br>
FinalThoughts: $finalthoughts <br>
EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);
```

I reviewed an earlier post and saw that capitalization was an issue, so I looked into that and still get this problem.  All other details look ok to me.... I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try leaving out the enctype="text/plain" from the HTML form, as that is non-standard.

More generally, though, you need to begin learning how to debug code if you are going to work with it. Debugging is a huge part of working with code. Using "here" documents (the <<<EOD construct) can create subtle bugs because there is a difficult to spot requirement that there be no blank spaces after the <<<EOD at the start or before the EOD; at the end.

I would first try substituting one of the fields for the "$body" in the last statement, to make sure the data is getting passed to the script at all, as in:

```
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $_REQUEST['what'], $headers);
```

Comment: Changed the entype and am now getting results.

Comment: I overlooked that one.  I stared hard at this code for a long time, My sincere thanks!